# What does 35401 mean in SOCKS proxy:127.0.0.1:35401

Tags: networking

I get the proxy configuration as :

```
Proxy all traffic
HTTP(S) proxy:127.0.0.1:32819
SOCKS proxy:127.0.0.1:35401
```

I get the idea that 127.0.0.1 is the local host which means  a simply ....0.0.0.1 in Ipv 6

What does the 32819 and 35401 mean?

it is hard to find any pattern

```
>>> bin(32819)
'0b1000000000110011'
>>> bin(35401)
'0b1000101001001001'
```

I read the story about Port 22 of SSH.
32819 and 35401 seem totally random here.

Ubuntu 18.10, I installed a VPN, this is its setting.

Comment: it's the automatic setting of VPN called lantern @user68186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the 32819 and 35401 mean?

Those are portnumbers.

> 32819 and 35401 seem totally random here.

Maybe. Maybe not. The owner of the specific software you installed decided on those.

[Here is a list of loads of portnumbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers); all the unofficial numbers are actually free for all; as long as a user does not install software that uses the same port number it is fine. And when a port is already in use: most software (can) use more ports.